# data_files differences between pip and setuptools

Tags: python-3.x, installation, pip, setuptools, data-files

I have a Python application that comes with a `setup.py` script and can be installed via Pip or setuptools. However, I'm finding some annoying differences between the two methods and I want to know the *correct way* of distributing data-files.

```
import glob
import setuptools

long_description = ''
setuptools.setup(
  name='creator-build',
  version='0.0.3-dev',
  description='Meta Build System for Ninja',
  long_description=long_description,
  author='Niklas Rosenstein',
  author_email='rosensteinniklas@gmail.com',
  url='https://github.com/creator-build/creator',
  py_modules=['creator'],
  packages=setuptools.find_packages('.'),
  package_dir={'': '.'},
  data_files=[
    ('creator', glob.glob('creator/builtins/*.crunit')),
  ],
  scripts=['scripts/creator'],
  classifiers=[
    "Development Status :: 5 - Production/Stable",
    "Programming Language :: Python",
    "Intended Audience :: Developers",
    "Topic :: Utilities",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries",
    "Topic :: Software Development :: Libraries :: Python Modules",
    ],
  license="MIT",
)
```

1. Using **Pip**, the files specified in `data_files` end up in `sys.prefix + '/creator'`.
2. Using **setuptools** (that is, running `setup.py` directly), the files end up in `lib/python3.4/site-packages/creator_build-0.0.3.dev0-py3.4.egg/creator`.

**Ideally**, I would like the files to always end up in the same location, independent from the installation method. I would also prefer the files to be put into the module directory (the way setuptools does it), but that could lead to problems if the package is installed as a *zipped Python Egg*.

How can I make sure the `data_files` end up in the same location with both installation methods? Also, how would I know if my module was installed as a *zipped Python Egg* and how can I load the data files then?

Answer (score 0):

I've been asking around and the general consensus including the [official docs](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide) is that:

> Warning data_files is deprecated. It does not work with wheels, so it should be avoided.

Instead, everyone appears to be pointing towards `include_package_data` instead.
There's a drawback here in that it doesn't allow for including things outside of your `src` root. Which means, if `creator` is outside `creator-build`, it won't include it. Even `package_data` will have this limitation.

The only workaround, if your data files are outside of your source files *(for instance, I'm trying to include `examples/*.py` for a lot of reasons we don't need to discuss)*, you can hot-swap them in, do the setup and then remove them.

```py
import setuptools, glob, shutil

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

shutil.copytree('examples', 'archinstall/examples')

setuptools.setup(
    name="archinstall",
    version="2.0.3rc4",
    author="Anton Hvornum",
    author_email="anton@hvornum.se",
    description="Arch Linux installer - guided, templates etc.",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://github.com/Torxed/archinstall",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3.8",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: GNU General Public License v3 (GPLv3)",
        "Operating System :: POSIX :: Linux",
    ],
    python_requires='>=3.8',
    package_data={'archinstall': glob.glob('examples/*.py')},
)

shutil.rmtree('archinstall/examples')
```

This is at best ugly, but works.
My folder structure for reference is (in the git repo):

```
.
├── archinstall
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── lib
│   │   ├── disk.py
│   │   └── exceptions.py
│   └── __main__.py
├── docs
│   ├── logo.png
├── examples
│   ├── guided.py
│   └── minimal.py
├── LICENSE
├── profiles
│   ├── applications
│   │   ├── awesome.json
│   │   ├── gnome.json
│   │   ├── kde.json
│   │   └── postgresql.json
│   ├── desktop.py
│   ├── router.json
│   ├── webserver.json
│   └── workstation.json
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

And this is the only way I can see how to include for instance my `profiles` as well as `examples` without moving them outside of the root of the repository *(which I'd prefer not to do, as I want users to easily find them when navigating to the repo on github)*.

And one final note. If you don't mind polluting the `src` directory, in my case that's just `archinstall`. You could symlink in whatever you need to include instead of copying it.

```
cd archinstall
ln -s ../examples ./examples
ln -s ../profiles ./profiles
```

That way, when `setup.py` or `pip` installs it, they'll end up in the `<package dir>` as it's root.